# Django Apache - Run script as Root

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

My django project calls a python file at a scheduled time using "at" scheduler. This is executed within my models.py

```
command = 'echo "python /path/to/script.py params" | /usr/bin/at -t [time] &> path/to/at.log'
status = os.system(command)
```

Where [time] is schedule time.
It works perfectly when I run it within Django Dev server (I usually run as root but it also works with other users as well)
But when I deployed my application on Apache using mod_wsgi, it doesn't work. at logs shows that the job was schedule but it doesn't execute it.
I tried everything from changing the ownership to www-data, permissions, made it into executable to all users, to setuid to root (Huge Security Issue)
The last thing I want to do is run apache as root user.

Comment: `at` command only takes the name of the executable which is to be scheduled for execution with no parameters. `echo` basically forces `at` to schedule the executable along with it's parameters. Look up the man page for `at`

Comment: I think you're missing a set of quotes.  Echo is written as a python keyword.

Answer (score 2):

Use [cron](http://linux.die.net/man/8/cron) or [celery](http://ask.github.com/celery/) for scheduled tasks. If you need to run something as root, it'd make sense to re-write your script as a simple daemon and run that as root, you can pass commands to it pretty easily with [zeromq](http://zeromq.org).

Comment: It ain't a recurring job, so can I use cron?

Comment: It's not recurring? I assumed it was. When/how often do you want this task run?

Comment: I would suggest using celery for spinning off tasks. You can use it without a broker, it's fairly easy to setup. To work around the root issue, you could setup a daemon process running as root, and issue commands to it with zeromq or something.

Comment: Thanks. I'll take a note of it next time. However, I made python write a bash file and made at execute that file to circumvent the root issue. However I noted that this issue only turns up on the production with apache on it.